# lldb isn't producing any data-on-demand

Tags: debugging, xcode5, lldb

Scenario: a) In Xcode 5 debug mode; and hence, all complier flags set accordingly.
          b) I'm able to see the local variables in the debugger variable viewer:

[image]

**Question:** How do I make the LLDB debugger show variable values on demand?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that my /Library/Developer/Xcode folder was "corrupt" via testing on a different account to learn that the Xcode debugger behaved correctly.

So I merely trashed the Xcode folder and began again.
This time, the Xcode debugger behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you mean with “on demand”?
Is your question related to the fact that

```
po theAnimation
```

did not produce any output?

Comment: Correct.  I eventually found that my /Library/Developer/Xcode folder was corrupt.   So I merely trashed it and began again.   It appears to work now.